# What are the Square Brackets around the class name?

Tags: html, css

I am working with a section of the website build by someone else I have found square brackets around the name of the classes, can someone explain what are these used for?

```
<div class="[ slide__text slide__text--padding ]">
    <div data-vc class="[ align--center ]">
        <div class="[ slide__text-inner ] animate--fade-in-shift-right">
            <span class="[ slide__text-sub-heading ] [ text--reg-sans ]">
                <span class="wpcs_price" id="wpcs_5d0771514bd19" data-amount=2550000><span class="wpcs_price_symbol">INR</span>&nbsp;48,350,551.13</span>
                &mdash; Zulal, Dubai </span>
            <h3 class="[ slide__text-heading ] [ heading--medium-large ]">
                Villa / HouseFor Sale <em>Zulal, Dubai</em>
            </h3>
            <a href="#" class="[ btn btn--narrow btn--outline ]">View</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, seems to be a bit different case than what the mentioned duplicate contains though. Actually, this here looks more like someone who did not know what they were doing introduced random brackets. They are separated from the rest by spaces, so `[` and `]` here constitute individual class names on their own. Those could in theory be used to select elements, but I doubt there’s actually any real purpose behind that here, looks much more like someone didn’t know what they were doing to begin with IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping related classes in your markup where the square brackets could be used to group.
Please, read this [Grouping related classes in your markup](https://csswizardry.com/2014/05/grouping-related-classes-in-your-markup/)

Comment: This article was really helpful since I had no way of contacting the actual person who wrote the code. It gave me a clear picture of what it was used for.